# Unable to stop a streaming dataflow on google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

There is a streaming dataflow running on google cloud (Apache beam 2.5). The dataflow was showing some system lag so I tries to update that dataflow with --update flag. Now the old dataflow is in Updating state and the new dataflow that initiated after the update process is in Pending state. 
Now at this point everything is stuck. I am unable to stop/cancel the jobs now. Old job is still in updating state and no status change operation is permitted. I tried to change the state of the job using gcloud dataflow jobs cancel and REST api but it's showing job cannot be updated as it's in RELOAD state. The new initiate job is in not started/pending state. Unable to change the state of this as well. It's showing job is not in condition to perform this operation.

Please let me know how to stop/cancel/delete this streaming dataflow.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to cancel the job from both command line `gcloud` tool and web console UI? If nothing works, I think you need to contact [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/).